# $f$ and $g$ extended real value functions, $|f+g| \leq |f|+|g|$, what if $f=\infty$ and $g=-\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis

If $f$ and $g$ take infinite values of opposite sign at some point, i.e. $f(x)=\infty$ and $g(x)=-\infty$ for some value of $x$, then $f+g$ is not a properly defined function. So how can we still make this claim that $|f+g| \leq |f|+|g|$?

Answer (score 2):

If $f=\infty$ then $f$ is not a "properly defined function" unless you specify what flavor of nonstandard analysis you're working with. In specifying that, you specify what $f+g$ is.

In any case, no matter what you mean by "$f=\infty$", it should satisfy:

If $f=\infty$ then $|f|=\infty$

If $x\geq 0$, then $\infty+x=\infty$

For all $x$, $x\leq \infty$

In this case, no matter what you mean by $f+g$, we have $|f+g|\leq |f|+|g|=\infty$

Comment: I mean that $f(x)=\infty$ for some value $x$ since $f$ is an extended real valued function. I should have been more clear.

Comment: @Andrew I never addressed whether $f$ was infinite at a single point or on the whole line. Everything I said works for both.

Comment: Where does your post address the situation $|\infty - \infty|$ ? Thanks.

Comment: @Andrew The first two sentences.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are wondering for maps from some metric space to the extended real line. If this is the case, note that on the extended real line we do not use the usual metric; instead, we can use the metric constructed in the way: Let $h: x \mapsto x/(1+|x|)$ on $\Bbb{R}$. Then $h$ makes $\Bbb{R}$ in bijection with $]-1,1[$. Extend $h$ to be a bijection between the extended real line and $[-1,1]$ by defining $h(+\infty) := 1$ and $h(-\infty) := -1$; then by proof the map $d: (x,y) \mapsto |h(x) - h(y)|$ is a metric on the extended real line.

Now it is clear that, if $M$ is a metric space and if $f,g$ map $M$ to the extended real line with the metric $d$, then of course we have the triangle inequality involving $f,g$.